# Codeigniter urlencoded string in form input

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode

I have a form with an input field that accepts url.

Everything works fine until someone tried submitting a url with url encoded elements. The url looks something like that

`http://example.com/a=xx&b=%23yy`

I am receiving this string as `http://example.com/a=xx&b=#yy`

Even before any form verification, `$this->input->post('url')` decoded the url encoded elements. I need to receive it exactly as entered.

I tried with a regular and multipart form.

Any idea what is causing that?

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Normally? Or are you involving JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put XSS filtering to TRUE globally in application/config.php?

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

If so you can disable the filtering by setting the optional parameter like this:

```
$this->input->post('url', FALSE)
```

Also check to see if the "Allowed URL Characters" in application/config.php is sane.

I would also play around with URLEncode/decode both client- and serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CodeIgniter's input class have some magic in it. Try to print_r your $_POST directly. Does that url get unaffected there?

Comment: It is pretty interesting. Maybe you should use firebug or something to check, what data is actually being sent.

Comment: yeah, tried that, it's submitted correctly, it's breaking when it hits php

Comment: That's most interesting bug. It has to be some php.ini setting or xss protection.

Comment: One more try. If you get data directly from php://input, does this behavior still happen? I mean $str = file_get_contents("php://input"); print $str;